# PHP - Sort Multidimensional Array by string

Tags: php

I have an array called "$myarray", which looks like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [PrinterID] => 4
        [PrinterName] => PRT04_GL
        [UserID] => 1
        [isDefaultPrinter] => 0
        [isMapped] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [PrinterID] => 1
        [PrinterName] => PRT01_Zentral
        [UserID] => 
        [isDefaultPrinter] => 0
        [isMapped] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [PrinterID] => 2
        [PrinterName] => PRT02_BH
        [UserID] => 
        [isDefaultPrinter] => 0
        [isMapped] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [PrinterID] => 3
        [PrinterName] => PRT03_EDV
        [UserID] => 
        [isDefaultPrinter] => 0
        [isMapped] => 1
    )
```

I want to sort the data by ["PrinterName"]. The wanted result would be:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [PrinterID] => 1
        [PrinterName] => PRT01_Zentral
        [UserID] => 
        [isDefaultPrinter] => 0
        [isMapped] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [PrinterID] => 2
        [PrinterName] => PRT02_BH
        [UserID] => 
        [isDefaultPrinter] => 0
        [isMapped] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [PrinterID] => 3
        [PrinterName] => PRT03_EDV
        [UserID] => 
        [isDefaultPrinter] => 0
        [isMapped] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [PrinterID] => 4
        [PrinterName] => PRT04_GL
        [UserID] => 1
        [isDefaultPrinter] => 0
        [isMapped] => 0
    )
```

Based on [this](https://paulund.co.uk/sort-multi-dimensional-array-value) example I tried the following:

```
uasort($myarray, 'sort_by_order');
function sort_by_order ($a, $b) {
  return $a['PrinterName'] - $b['PrinterName'];
}
```

This does not work. I get errors like "A non-numeric value encountered ...", of course because my values are strings and the function is for numeric values.

How do I sort the array?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
I think I did find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php/17364128#17364128). I used this and it seems to work:

```
uasort($myarray, 'sort_by_order');
function sort_by_order ( $a, $b ) { return strcmp($a['PrinterName'], $b['PrinterName']); }
```

Comment: change your return statement to `return strcmp($a["PrinterName"], $b["PrinterName"]);`

Comment: Yes its working, Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Please try with $a['PrinterName'] > $b['PrinterName']

It will compare the values

Comment: The `usort` callback expects a value < 0, 0, or > 0; not `true` or `false`.